# Can't deserialize Instant after serialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

So I have a problem with deserializing an `Instant` variable with Jackson. Basically, a class stores an Instant like this:

```
class Example {
   @JsonProperty("createdAt") 
   private Instant createdAt;

   public example() {
      this.createdAt = Instant.now();
   }
}
```

Later, in the unit test, I get ahold of the serialized version of the instance of the `Example` class which looks like this:

```
{"createdAt":1538069901.720000000} // content of the payload variable
```

And then the error comes when I try to deserialize it:

```
 private final ObjectMapper JSON_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
 Example ex1 = JSON_MAPPER.readValue(payload, Example.class);
```

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of java.time.Instant: no double/Double-argument
>   constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value
>   (1.53806990172E9)

This kind of make sense, that the value of `createdAt` is seen as a double(`1538069901.720000000`) but how else am I supposed to do this ?

Comment: You'll need the [Java Time module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime).

Comment: That's it, you solved my problem, thanks!.